# Should I make the code for my personal web sites open-source? What are the security implications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, open-source, github

I'm just about to rewrite my personal site/blog using ASP.NET 4/MVC. I usually use my private Subversion server for version control, but for this project I'm intending to use Git/GitHub —I've been using Git more and more recently and prefer the way it works. I'd also like to make my code open-source in case anyone else wants to use it to learn from.

**My question is this: if I make the source code of my personal site publicly available on GitHub, am I exposing myself to an increased risk of security breaches?**

I'm not concerned about intellectual property here, just about security—whatever code I write will be fairly basic anyway.

I realise that a) the open-source community leans very much toward the white-hat and b) my tiny web site is not by any means a worthwhile target.

Having said that, if I'm publishing my code and I make a mistake which results in a security hole (and I'm positive that at some stage I will, nobody's perfect), it only takes one malicious person to exploit it rather than letting me know and I'm screwed, aren't I?.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a private GitHub repository?  Best of both worlds!

Comment: @Nilpo How is that the best of *both* worlds? Using a private repo removes the "open source" world entirely...

Comment: You can still release your code with an Open Source license, but only allow access to the repository upon request.  This is the only way to somewhat control who sees it.  If you release code into the wild you have to assume the risk that at some point someone with malicious intent is going to look a look at it if your project is popular.  Personally, I don't tend to worry about it.  The benefits of sharing typically outweigh any risk and there are typically far more people willing to help you secure it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open-source it, it has a higher chance of being hacked, but you have a much higher chance of being told about it. If you don't, you may not get told about it if it happens.